# PHP - Date and time variable in Australia Timezone

Tags: php, html, forms, date

I log user visits of a page in a separate file and it gets confusing because it's all in a different timezone. Therefore if I'm looking for a user who visited at 1/1/18 at xx.x.xx, it will be very annoying and confusing.

The code is this for the date variable

```
$dateTime = date('d/m/y G:i:s:e');
```

This will output

```
07/01/18 2:35:47:UTC
```

How can I change the timezone from UTC to Australian Eastern Time (AET) || UTC +10:00 / +11:00

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/australia

Thanks heaps in advance!

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your file, add

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

or, instead of 'UTC', add one of the strings for Australian cities listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney')); 
echo dateTime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```